# Solving $e^{0.0002n} + e^{0.0003n} = 0.01$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve an exponent equation which is:

$$
        e^{0.0002n} + e^{0.0003n} = 0.01 
$$

Please help me with this equation.

Thanks.

Comment: Factoring will do the trick.

Comment: If you don't add some context (where does this strange problem come from, what have you tried, where exactly is the problem), your question will be closed in almost no time.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $e^{0.0001n}=t$

$$t^2+t^3 = 0.01$$

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @DatBoi's answer, if $t=0.1$, then

$$t^2+t^3=0.011$$ and we have a good approximation. Now using a Newton's iteration,

$$t'=t-\frac{t^2+t^3-0.01}{2t+3t^3}=0.1-\frac{0.001}{0.23}=0.09565\cdots$$

You can use a few more iterations, or use the general formula for the cubic equation. $t$ gives $n$.

Comment: The general formula for the cubic equation...you'd need a good calculator for the cube roots of complex numbers, then. :) The equation has three real solutions (near 0.1, near -0.1 and near -1).

Comment: @ProfessorVector: the trigonometric solution will do.

Comment: Yes, I know. $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{20\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3-\arcsin\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)}=0.095540135658765005554070926434663596873$$

Comment: FWIW, just iterating $t'=\sqrt{0.01/(t+1)}$ converges pretty quickly.

Comment: @PM2Ring: that's right. It converges to $15$ correct decimals in $10$ iterations (vs. $4$ for Newton). It is better than $t'=\sqrt{0.01-t^3}$ ($17$ iterations).

Comment: Well sure, Newton's converges quadratically. (And for this equation it doesn't take a square root). I like playing with these simple recurrence relationships, just to see how quickly they converge or diverge. Sometimes they can be useful to generate initial approximations to feed into Newton's method.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, your expression is not equal to $0.09554...$ but it is equal to $0.08963301...$ You should divide $\arcsin$ by 3 too.

Comment: @Angelo Oops, that was a typo, it should be $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{20\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3-\frac13\arcsin\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)}=0.095540135658765005554070926434663596873$$

Comment: Yes, now it is correct

Comment: Moreover the denominator could be reduced to $$20\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;x=e^{-0.0001n}\;$.

The equation

$e^{0.0002n} + e^{0.0003n} = 0.01$

turns into

$x^3-100x-100=0$.

The only positive solution is

$x=\dfrac{20}{3}\sqrt{3}\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{3}\right)\simeq10.46680532$

where $\;\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)\simeq74.94135263^\text{o}.$

Hence

$n=-10000\ln\left[\dfrac{20}{3}\sqrt{3}\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{3}\right)\right]\simeq-23482.08851$

where $\;\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)\simeq74.94135263^\text{o}.$